# Metric for how symmetric a matrix is

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, symmetric-matrices

Given a square NxN matrix A, what is a measure of how symmetric A is?

I can get the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of A as:

$A_{sym}=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^{T})$

and

$A_{anti}=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^{T})$

Is there some commonly used function, $F(A,A_{sym},A_{anti})$, that gives a measure of how symmetric a matrix is? E.g. something like the ratio of the determinants of $A_{sym}$ and $A_{anti}$?

Comment: I would just use the norm of the antisymmetric part. The symmetric matrices are a subspace of all matrices and this norm describes the distance from $A$ to the nearest symmetric matrix, which is its symmetric part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One simple possibity:

$s \equiv (|A_{sym}|-|A_{anti}|)/(|A_{sym}|+|A_{anti}|)$

Here |·| is whatever matrix norm you choose.  Then $-1\le s \ \le +1$ with the lower bound saturated for an antisymmetric matrox, upper bound saturated for a symmetric one.

Comment: Yeah seems reasonable. Could also shift and scale so is a scalar on [0,1]: .5*(s+1)

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi, can you suggest some norm(s) that would be appropriate in this context?

Comment: Any matrix norm could work, so it's up to you really.